# underlying behavior type does not implement the IServiceBehavior interface

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I've got a WCF Rest webservice that receives JSON from an external vendor, and I'm trying to archive to disk the exact JSON received via a CustomBehavior. I put the CustomBehavior in a separate .DLL from the web service, gave it a strong key, and GAC'ed it.

Full Error Text:

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/64525900 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/SQRTREST/SQRTREST.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception
>   during compilation.  The exception message is: Cannot add the behavior
>   extension 'WcfAuditBehavior' to the service behavior named
>   'ServiceBehaviour' because the underlying behavior type does not
>   implement the IServiceBehavior interface. (e:\IISSite
>   Folders\ServiceEndPoints\SQRTREST\web.config line 50). --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Cannot add the
>   behavior extension 'WcfAuditBehavior' to the service behavior named
>   'ServiceBehaviour' because the underlying behavior type does not
>   implement the IServiceBehavior interface. (e:\IISSite
>   Folders\ServiceEndPoints\SQRTREST\web.config line 50)

Despite the error above, look to me like I do implement the IServiceBehavior interface.   I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123958/error-while-implementing-ierrorhandler-cannot-add-the-behavior-extension), and didn't quite seem to understand how putting the iServiceBehavior on the ErrorHandler applies.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
//using System.Web.Services.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;

using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Schema;
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SQRT_WCFAuditBehavior
    {

    public class WcfAuditBehaviorClass : BehaviorExtensionElement, IServiceBehavior 
        {
        //* methods for BehaviorExtensionElement 
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
            {
            return new WcfAuditMessageInspector();
            }

        public override Type BehaviorType
            {
            get
                {
                return typeof(WcfAuditMessageInspector);
                }
            }
        //* methods for IServiceBehavior 
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
            {
            }

        private IErrorHandler GetInstance()
            {
            return new MyErrorHandler();
            }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
            {
            IErrorHandler errorHandlerInstance = GetInstance();
            foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
                {
                dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandlerInstance);
                }
            }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
            {
            }

        }

    public class WcfAuditMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
        {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {
            var buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();

            this.LogMessage(buffer, "Request");
            return null;
            }


        private void LogMessage(MessageBuffer buffer, string messageType)
            {
            var originalMessage = buffer.CreateMessage();
            string messageContent;

            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                {
                using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
                    {
                    originalMessage.WriteMessage(xmlTextWriter);
                    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                    xmlTextWriter.Close();
                    }
                messageContent = stringWriter.ToString();
                }

            // log messageContent to the database 
            try
                {
                // TODO copy logic from main routine to get path from web.config and Environment parm 
                string diskConsumePathName = @"\\myserver\Messages\System\Inbox\OrderIn\";
                string formatDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd__hh_mm_sss");  // make sure both files below have exact same date/tiem stamp 
                string errorFilename = "System_" + formatDateTime + "_" + messageType + "_RawJSON.txt";

                string diskErrorFullPathName = System.IO.Path.Combine(diskConsumePathName, errorFilename);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(diskErrorFullPathName, messageContent);
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                // todo - write to event log? 
                }

            return;
            }


        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
            var buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
            this.LogMessage(buffer, "Response");
            return;
            }
        }


    /*
    public class WcfAuditBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
        {
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
            {
            return new WcfAuditBehavior();
            }

        public override Type BehaviorType
            {
            get { return typeof(WcfAuditBehavior); }
            }
        }

     */

    public class MyFault
        {

        }

    public class MyErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
        {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
            {
            return true;
            }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message msg)
            {
            var vfc = new MyFault();
            var fe = new FaultException<MyFault>(vfc);
            var fault = fe.CreateMessageFault();
            msg = Message.CreateMessage(version, fault, "http://ns");
            }
        }


    }
```

Web.Config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SQRT_WCF.SQRTREST" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding" contract="SQRT_WCF.ISQRTREST" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="WcfAuditBehavior" type="SQRT_WCFAuditBehavior.WcfAuditBehaviorClass, SQRT_WCFAuditBehavior, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=acd8bac56d3776b8" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <WcfAuditBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```