# How to dispose client context (sharepoint online) in wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am getting data from sharepoint online using WCF that is hosted in IIS. I decided to handle all my errors using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3178164/1074179) example. In my code I am using ClientContext class that needs to be disposed in a right way

```
  ClientContext _context = new ClientContext(_url);
  var list = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
  ListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
  _context.Load(item, i => i[Description], i => i[Picture], i => i[Title], i => i.Id);
  _context.ExecuteQuery();
  _context.Dispose();
```

But if I get exception in _context.ExecuteQuery(); I go to HandleError method

```
public bool HandleError(Exception error)
{
    return true;
}
```

The question is: How to Dispose client context in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go this way:

```
using(ClientContext _context = new ClientContext(_url))
{
    var list = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
    ListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
    _context.Load(item, i => i[Description], i => i[Picture], i => i[Title], i => i.Id);
    _context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

or

```
try
{  
  ClientContext _context = new ClientContext(_url);
  var list = _context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
  ListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
  _context.Load(item, i => i[Description], i => i[Picture], i => i[Title], i => i.Id);
  _context.ExecuteQuery();
}
finally
{  
  _context.Dispose();
}
```